# Why can't I add a foreign key constraint this way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `relation` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
     `gender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `unique_relation` (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    CREATE TABLE `invite` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `date_sent` date NOT NULL,
     `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `relation_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `fk_user` (`user_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The SQL statement executed was:

```
ALTER TABLE `invite` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_relation`  
FOREIGN KEY (`relation_id`) 
REFERENCES `relation` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Mysql Error:

**`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'dbtest.#sql-d00_39' (errno: 121).`**

The **relation.id** and **invite.relation_id** columns are of the same type int(10) unsigned

**UPDATE**
The table invite is empty while adding this key.
The table relation has 3 rows.

Comment: Actually, invite table is empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
ALTER TABLE invite
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_relation
FOREIGN KEY (relation_id)
REFERENCES relation(id)
```

According to the doc syntax is correct [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The DDL for Foreign Key creation now automatically includes statements to specify actions on "Delete" and "Update". However, for "Delete", it includes the statement "ON DELETE RESTRICT", which does not appear to be a valid T-SQL statement.

TRY THIS :

ALTER TABLE invite WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT fk_relation 
FOREIGN KEY (relation_id) REFERENCES relation (id)